# Determine the minimal value of $\frac{3a}{b+c}+\frac{4b}{c+a}+\frac{5c}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive real numbers. Determine the minimal value of
$$\frac{3a}{b+c}+\frac{4b}{c+a}+\frac{5c}{a+b}.$$

I have solved this problem using Chebyshev's and Nesbitt's inequalities.
The actual answer was $$\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{5})^2 - 12$$ which is approximately 5.8. Help me understand where I went wrong.
[image: Me using my bird brain]

In the image I have misspelt 'Nesbitt' as 'Nessbit'.

Comment: please don't use all caps and choose a more descriptive title.